# How to trigger link from sql trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

I would like to trigger a link via sql trigger. Every Friday night 11:00pm link should trigger from sql trigger.

I have not written any sql trigger so far so I need your help.

Is this possible to trigger a link via sql?

Comment: Please add a database tag (as the `sql` tag says to do) for the DB that you use. ... For MySQL/MariaDB, what you are asking is more like an [event](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/events/). Triggers are NOT time sensitive, but take actions based on when an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE happens.

Comment: Thanks Paul, Event i want to run on specific time and it should trigger link. it is possible? to add event is my sql?

Comment: Do you mean like a website hyperlink? ... No that won't happen. The DB knows nothing about web. I thought you meant for some DB-level handling for whatever the link might typically do.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most products have their own trigger syntax.)